# DocuSign integration tests

Tags: integration-testing, docusignapi

I am writing an application that should interact with DocuSign to create envelopes and then download the signed document when all the signatories have signed.

There are several other use cases, but that does not matter for this question.

I am wondering what is the best way to write automated integration tests.
Do I need to automate the interaction of the signatories withe DocuSign? This would mean that I have to receive the email, click the link, etc...

Even if it seems possible, it does not seem ideal. Is there a way to "simulate" in a dev environment the actions of the signatories?

Answer (score 4):

There has been a lot of talks if a document can be signed without viewing it. And the conclusion was that NO, user cannot sign a document without viewing it. User has to view/see what is to be signed. So, that part needs to be automated using Selenium or one of its "flavors" or pretty much any UI automation you are comfortable with. And Yes, that involves receiving email, clicking the link, opening a document and signing it. You can use a Mailinator or any other email service which API you can leverage to facilitate things for you.

As for other parts of DocuSign integration automation it is encouraged to use API (makes things more stable).

So, very simple workflow steps would look like this:

1. Use API to prepare environment, sent variables and values (in your product and in DocuSign)
2. Send envelope for signing using DocuSign API
3. Get the link to the document
4. Sign using UI automation
5. Do verification (of envelope status and more) using DocuSign API

Comment: I understand that it should never be possible in a production environment to sign the contract without viewing it. For the test automation though, it would be help to have an API to "simulate" the signing. 
About the use of the API for the testing, because I am interested in testing our application, I do not want to directly use the DocuSign API: the application will do it.

Comment: Seconded the general premise... it's unfortunate that there isn't testing tools for circumstances where developers should have zero need to touch the front end. I'm doing something similar where the only thing I care about is the signed documents... yet I can't just press a button to create signed documents without the entire process - which I have no use of - that comes before.