# DocuSignAPI - Sign an envelope via API

Tags: postman, docusignapi, sign

We are creating an application that processes signed documents. As part of the testing process, I'd like to automate the creation and signing of sample documents. **How can I sign the documents via postman?**

Using the Postman scripts located at the [DocuSign/blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman/), I can authenticate:

```
https://{{hostenv}}/restapi/{{apiVersion}}/login_information?api_password=true
{
    "loginAccounts": [
        {
            "name": "Personal",
            "accountId": "9",
            "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/9",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "userName": "Chris",
            "userId": "",
            "email": "",
            "siteDescription": ""
        }
    ],
    "apiPassword": "="
}
```

and then create an envelope to be signed...

```
{{baseUrl}}/envelopes

{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "{{signer1Email}}",
        "name": "{{signer1Name}}",
        "recipientId": 1,
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "xPosition": "100",
              "yPosition": "100",
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "blank1.pdf",
      "documentBase64": "JVBERi0x..."
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Is there a way - via postman - to sign the envelope that was just created?

I've been exploring a more involved setup (Selenium, etc) but was wondering if documents can be signed via postman.

Answer (score 1):

As Inbar states, you can't automatically sign an envelope using the DocuSign API. One alternative is to Correct the envelope to change the Signer to a Carbon Copy recipient, which would immediately complete their role in the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sign envelopes via the REST API (or any other API).
You can use UI automation techniques to click things on the page and sign envelopes this way. 
there's a similar question that was asked here, it has an answer from an automation expert who did this - [DocuSign integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249383/docusign-integration-tests)